# Prove there exists infinitely many real numbers $a$ such that $a(a - 3\{a\})$ is an integer

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification

> Prove there exists infinitely many real numbers $a$ such that $a(a - 3\{a\})$ is an integer. $\{a\}$ = fractional part of a number.

Here is my proof. Are there any fallacies that I’m missing? Alternate proofs are also welcome :)

Let $S$ be the set of reals obeying this property.
Let $\lambda$ be the greatest real in this set.

Then let $ \alpha = \lambda  + (1 - \{\lambda\})$

(In essence, $\alpha$ takes the number and rounds up to the nearest integer.)

Since $\alpha >  \lambda$, $\alpha$ is not in S.

But $\alpha$ is an integer and all integers obey this property.

Thus, $\alpha$ is a member of $S$,
which completes the proof by contradiction.

Comment: What about letting $a$ be an integer? There are infinitely many, and they seem to work. So there is really nothing to prove.

Comment: Isn't that true for all $a\in\mathbb{N}$? And $\mathbb{N}\subset\mathbb R$.

Comment: The argument is correct but unncessary: the fact that every integer is in $S$ already shows that $S$ is infinite.

Comment: Yes all, I realised that it’s true for all integers, hence true, but it seemed a bit “weak” to me, hence this proof.

Comment: Maybe interesting to exclude the cases where $a\in \mathbb Z$.  Then there are still infinitely many examples (such as $a=k+\frac 12$ for odd integers $k$)...not sure what the whole list looks like.

Comment: @lulu, all rational solutions are of the form $a=k+\frac 12$ .

Comment: @lhf I figured...is it obvious?  I'd say that was worth writing up.  Worth noting that of course there are irrational solutions...$\frac {1}{\sqrt{2}}$ for one.

Answer (score 3):

Let's see what rational solutions exist.

Let $a=n +\dfrac pq$,with $n,p,q \in \mathbb Z$, $|p|<q$, $\gcd(p,q)=1$. Then $\{a\} = \dfrac pq$ and
$$
a(a - 3\{a\}) = (n +\dfrac pq)(n -\dfrac {2p}q) = n^2-\dfrac{npq+2p^2}{q^2}
$$
This is an integer iff $q^2$ divides $npq+2p^2$.

If $q^2$ divides $npq+2p^2$, then $q$ divides $2p^2$, and so $q$ divides $2$, because $gcd(p,q)=1$. Therefore, $q=1$ and $p=0$, or $q=2$ and $p=\pm1$.

In the first case, $a=n$ is an integer.

In the second case, $a=n\pm\dfrac12$, but we still need that $4$ must divide $2np-2p^2$ and so $2$ must divide $np+p^2=\pm n+1$, and so $n$ is odd.

Therefore, the only rational, non-integral, solutions are of the form $n\pm\dfrac12$, with $n$ odd. It is easy to check that these are indeed solutions.

Answer (score 1):

> Alternate proofs are also welcome :)

The other answer shows all such $a$'s where $\{a\}$ is rational (which is completely sufficient), I thought it would be interesting to look also at the other cases (basically to find them all).

Since $a$ is positive, let's focus on interval $a \in (n,n+1)$ for some integer $n \geq 0$. Then we have $a=n+e$ where $e \in (0,1)$, and the target expression becomes
$$
a(a-3\{a\})=(n+e)(n+e-3e)=(n+e)(n-2e)\\=n^2-ne-2e^2.
$$
We can see this will be integer if and only if $ne+2e^2$ is an integer. So let's put $k=ne+2e^2$, and solving the quadratic for $e$ we find $e=\frac{-n \pm \sqrt{n^2+8k}}{4}$. So we have $n^2+8k \geq 0$ (or equivalently $k \geq -\frac{1}{8}n^2$). Since also $e > 0$, we must have
$e=\frac{1}{4}(\sqrt{n^2+8k}-n)$. Now using the conditions $0<e$ and $e<1$ we solve for $k$.

From $e>0$, we see $\sqrt{n^2+8k}>n$. Both sides are non-negative, hence $n^2+8k>n^2$ leading to $k>0$.

From $e<1$ we see $\sqrt{n^2+8k}-n<4$, or $\sqrt{n^2+8k}<n+4$. Again both sides are non-negative, so $n^2+8k<n^2+8n+16$, leading to $k<n+2$.

Thus $k \in \{1,2,\dots,n+1\}$ and at the same time $k \geq -\frac{1}{8}n^2$, where the second condition is clearly redundant.

So  to summarize, for fixed $n$, choose any $k \in \{1,2,\dots,n+1\}$ and then $a=n+\frac{1}{4}(\sqrt{n^2+8k}-n)$ will satisfy the condition. It can be shown that $a(a-3\{a\})=n^2-k$. Also by the construction, these cover all solutions.

As an example, for $n=10$ and $k=2$ we have $a=\frac{15}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{29}}{2}$ and $a(a-3\{a \})=98$.

It's clear this implies there are infinitely many solutions. Also we actually haven't used anything about rationality of $e$, so the solutions with $e=\frac{1}{2}$ are included as well.